# Convert xml to hashmap and vice-versa

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xml-parsing

I have a xml schema with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page>
   <body>
      <item attr1="a1" attr2="a2" />
      <item attr1="a1" attr2="a2" attr3="a3" attr4="a4" attr_n="a_n" />
      <item attr1="a1" attr2="a2" attr3="a3" attr4="a4" attr_n="a_n">
         <element1>abc</element1>
         <element2>xyz</element2>
         <element_n>nnn</element_n>
      </item>
   </body>
</page>
```

The item tag can have n number of attributes and elements, known or unknown. Also it may or may not have any element.

I want to parse this xml into java pojo, I prefer using hashmap for the field `item`. It parses rest of the things but the elements/attributes of `item` are not getting parsed. It is always null. Any suggestions on how to achieve this will be appreciated.

My pojo structure is like this:

Page.java

```
public class Page
{
    private Body body;

    public Body getBody ()
    {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody (Body body)
    {
        this.body = body;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [body = "+body+"]";
    }
}
```

Body.java

```
public class Body
{
    private List<Map<String, Object>> item;

    public List<Map<String, Object>> getItem ()
    {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem (List<Map<String, Object>> item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [item = "+item+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd do this with JAXB and use `@XmlAnyAttribute` in `Item` to map attributes to a `java.util.Map`.

Comment: It works for `java.util.Map`. But mine is `List<Map<String, Object>>` and it doesn't work for that

Comment: You can do `List<Item>` and have your `Map` in `Item`. That's almost the same.

Comment: That would change my xml structure

Comment: No, it won't. Your Java classes, however, will not be *exactly* like you want them, that's right. But it's a low price to pay, from my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `xsd` schema file. You can get plugins in eclipse which can convert an `xml` to `xsd`. Using frameworks like `jibx`, `jaxb` etc create schema classes. These libraries have classes to convert object to `xml` and vice-versa.

Comment: I tried using jaxb, but it fails to initialise the item object, look at my pojo structure.

Comment: There are tools in these libraries which will create schema classes with required annotations for you. You need not to handcraft them.

Comment: I know these libraries create schema classes for me. But these attributes keep on increasing and decreasing, those are dynamic values. Thats why I don't want to keep a fixed schema

Comment: I believe you should be using json instead of xml then. That would fit in your requirement and easy to be parsed.

Comment: well, I use json as well as xml. It is based on the format parameter in the request.  If format = xml, I send xml. If format is json, I send json